# @Around advice access to thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart

Tags: annotations, aspectj

I'm trying to code an aspect using the annotation style.  I am creating an "around" advice, but I can't seem to find any way to get access to thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart from within the advice method.  Any time I try to define an argument to it, I get an error from the ajc compiler.

Here's the declaration of my pointcut and advice:

```
@Pointcut("call(@xxx.api.annotation.InvokeOnEDT * gov.raptor..*.*(..))")
void invokeOnEDTPointCut()
{/*empty*/}

@Around("invokeOnEDTPointCut(thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart)")
public Object invokeOnEDT(final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart) throws Throwable
{...}
```

I know that this fails to compile, I provide it to show what I "want" to do, but can't find a way to do.  I have spent hours searching the web and the only examples I can find are for Before or After advice, and they seem to allow this syntax.  The Around advice clearly behaves differently, but nothing I've found discusses it.

The error I receive when I compile is this:

```
[ERROR] ...\aspects\DispatchEDTAspects.java:42:0::0 incompatible number of arguments to pointcut, expected 0 found 1
```

Any ideas on how to access thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart from within the advice method?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
@Around("call(@xxx.api.annotation.InvokeOnEDT * gov.raptor..*.*(..))")
        public Object advice(final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, ProceedingJoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart) throws Throwable {
    ...
    }
```